# Appending HTML that allows AngularJS functionality

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Currently I have these following code,

```
var myApp= angular.module('myApp', ['myCTRL']);
var myCTRL= angular.module('myCTRL', []);

myCTRL.controller('myCTRL', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', function ($scope, $http, $window) {
    $http.get('/someURL').success(function (data) {
        $scope.recordObject = data.recordObject;
    });
    $scope.testFunction= function () {
      $scope.testModel= 'clicked!!!!!';

   };

}]);
```

Based on what I get from HTTP request, I would get a recordObject. Is there any way for me to create HTML template and compile it base off this recordObject? I am planning to create a complicated table which cannot be accomplished by ng-repeat tag.

First try, I  tried creating a div with id 'demoDirective' but this will just print out {{recordObject}}. If i try console.log(recordObject) it is undefined here too.

```
myCTRL.directive('demoDirective', function ($compile) {
    return {
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller, transcludeFn) {
            var html= '<div>{{recordObject}}</div>'
            $compile(html)(scope);
            element.append(test);
        }
    }
})
```

My second try is to use compile. The {{recordObject}} will get printed out. However, I cannot access recordObject in this function. I read that there is no way for me to access scope in compile function. I would like to perform login off recordObject to create the HTML I want.

```
myCTRL.directive('demoDirective', function ($compile) {
    return {
        replace: true,
        compile: function (element, attrs) {
        var html= '<div>{{recordObject}}</div>'
        element.replaceWith(html);
    }
})
```

My third try is to attach directive to myApp instead of myCTRL. I can access scope.recordObject in this case which is perfect. However, the html the I compile does not have ng- functionality.

```
myApp.directive("demoDirective", function ($compile) {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var html = '<input type="text" ng-model="testModel"> <button ng-click="testFunction()">testButton</button>;
        $compile(html)(scope);

    };
});
```

Comment: you are missing closing `'` in `.get` method

Comment: you are missing closing `'` in html also in third part

Comment: Hi thank you for pointing that out. It was just a typo while writing the question. In the real program the function does run!